# Values inside Openlayers map to change when unit change from Metric to imperial

Tags: scale, openlayers, units-of-measurement

Im using openlayers map where the i have few points in map and on clicking each it show its Northing, Easting values in a pop-up

When the user changes unit system from Metric to Imperial we observe the scale line unit changes in map. Similarly i need the Northing , Easting values of a point displayed to change based on unit (Metric - meter, Imperial - foot). below is the sample unit conversion

```
Eg: In metric (meter)
North - 26.27
East - 20

In Imperial (feet)
North - 86.20
East - 65.62
```

I expect the same conversion to happen inside map when unit change is done. I can receive the unit system changed inside map. But how to handle the unit conversion dynamically in map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaleline control isn't linked to your popup which presumably use projection units?

You would need to change the code for your popups, for example

```
var x = coord[0];
var y = coord[1];
if (scaleline.getUnits() == 'imperial') {
  x = x * 100 / (2.54 * 12);
  y = y * 100 / (2.54 * 12);
}
content.innerHTML = 'North - ' + y.toFixed(2) + '<br>East - ' + y.toFixed(2);
```